# Ubuntu Software Center look

Tags: 16.04, gnome, software-center

Whenever i open software center it looks like this:

[image: Software Center]

If I select any application, I am unable to read the text. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Screenshot looks fine.

Comment: Is the problem only with Flash?
Did you try changing the desktop theme?

Comment: Whenever i navigate to any application,it overrides the text underneath and the text becomes invisible. The problem is the same with any application that i search for in the software center. You could see that te text flash is not visible in the screenshot because i selected it.

Comment: I had this problem some time ago, and it fixed automatically when I updated the application. Are you sure you got the last version ? Also you should maybe try to enable the dark theme in the Tweak tool application, it sometimes help on color problems like this.

Comment: Your problem is typical of many third-party themes. What have you installed and how?